# How do i access usernameField and change its value to email according to this javascript library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Here is the code i wrote to use a nodejs library called passport-local-mongoose. And part of the documentation for this library, states that you can change the usernameField to "email" in order for passport-local to use email instead of username when authenticating. I'm new to JavaScript and i am struggling to use the options parameter to change the usernameField to "email" according to this documentation under the options section.
https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose

Here is my code

```
var mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//Creates a user credentials schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

//Set the schema to use passport-local-mongoose
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

//Export the user model to app.js
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation:

> When plugging in Passport-Local Mongoose plugin additional options can be provided to configure the hashing algorithm.

`User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, options);`

And listing possible values for options:

> usernameField: specifies the field name that holds the username.
>   Defaults to 'username'.

---

So you need to change:

```
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
```

to (Where *email* refers to the field you want to use as username)

```
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'});
```

**Full Code**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Creates a user credentials schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

//Set the schema to use passport-local-mongoose
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'});

//Export the user model to app.js
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Edit: typo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944290/how-to-use-mongoose-schemas-and-passport-with-nodejs-es6typescript

Answer (score 0):

```
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
```

Try changing the above line to the following:

```
let myOptions = {
  username: "email",
};

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose,myOptions);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944290/how-to-use-mongoose-schemas-and-passport-with-nodejs-es6typescript